# _list functions with _all_docs

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'd like to use a [`_list` function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions) to format the output of the [`_all_docs` view](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html).

I see a [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1139) was merged to support this usecase, however from the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/render.html?db-design-design-doc-list-list-name-view-name#db-design-design-doc-list-list-name-view-name) and the comments I can't figure out what the end-point for this would be.

I've tried on Cloudant, which doesn't seem to work:

`/db/_design/[design-doc]/_list/[list-name]/_all_docs`

Is it the case that this is not supported on Cloudant? I don't have a CouchDB install at hand to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not currently supported in Cloudant, but should be coming soon. As a workaround, you can create a custom view called `_all_docs` in the same design document as your list function:

```
…
  "views": {
    "_all_docs": {
      "map": "function(doc) { emit(doc._id, {\"rev\": doc._rev}) }"
    },
…
```

This will create a redundant index, which isn't ideal. This custom `_all_docs` also won't return design documents, where the "real" `_all_docs` will return design documents.

Comment: I don't need design documents, so that doesn't bother me, but it should be possible to use [view options](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html#view-options) to get them in your view (don't know if that works on Cloudant).

Comment: @NunoCruces I tested it and the `include_design` feature does work on Cloudant. So, if you enable this option then the workaround I outlined will be functionally identical to the built in `_all_docs` function.